# Python script not producing output

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been tasked with reading values inputted by a user(using a while loop) to then store them in a list/array whilst using `try: except:` to determine if a given input is invalid. In continuation, if the user inputs "done" as a value it will `break` the loop and `print()` the total, sum, and average of all the imputed values.

I have gotten this snippet so far:

```
class Input:
      def __init__(self, number_input_value, total_to_be_calculated, main_value):
            self.number_input_value = 0
            self.total_to_be_calculated = 0.0
            self.main_value = input('Enter A Number: ')
            self.number_input_value1 = float(self.main_value)

      def loop_get_inputs(self):
            while True:
                  self.main_value
                  if self.main_value == 'done':
                        break
                  try :
                        self.number_input_value1
                  except :
                        print('INVAL["VAL"]')
                        continue
                  self.number_input_value = self.number_input_value1
                  self.total_to_be_calculated = self.total_to_be_calculated + self.number_input_value1

            print ("Finished successfully!")
            print (
              self.total_to_be_calculated,
              self.number_input_value,
              self.total_to_be_calculated/self.number_input_value
            )

if __name__ in '__main__':
      Input
```

I have no clue what's wrong, because when it runs it outputs nothing.

Output:

```
>>>
```

Comment: It's a good question for someone who's learning, but also a sign you're missing some fundamentals. Do you have a good Python reference book or resource you can turn to? This is critical for learning. Tutorials and quick introductions have many gaps.

Answer (score 1):

You need create an instance of the class 'Input' and call the method:

```
##(self, number_input_value, total_to_be_calculated, main_value)

inp = Input(100, 1000, 10) 
#call the method
inp.loop_get_inputs()
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically:
1 - You have to initialize your class/object before using it.
2 - Having code on the construct is not recommend. You should call a public method of the class to start the "process".
3 - That try-except wasn't doing much. You can, for example, surround the string (from `input()`) cast to float and print INVALID if the input can't be casted.
4 - You can use `+=` to simplify `a = a + b`
5 - lower() will convert user input to lowercase, meaning that DONE, done and DoNe (etc) will be considered as "quit" input.

Does this make sense?

```
class Input:
    def __init__(self):
        self.number_inputs = 0
        self.total = 0.0

    def run(self):
        self.__get_user_values()
        print(f"total: '{self.total}'")
        print(f"number_inputs: '{self.number_inputs}'")
        print(f"average: '{self.total / self.number_inputs}'")

    def __get_user_values(self):
        while True:
            value = input('Enter A Number: ')
            if value.lower() == 'done':
                break

            if self.__is_valid_input(value):
                self.total += float(value)
                self.number_inputs += 1

    def __is_valid_input(self, value) -> bool:
        try:
            float(value)
            return True
        except ValueError:
            print('INVAL["VAL"]')
            return False


if __name__ in '__main__':
    input_wrapper = Input()
    input_wrapper.run()
```

Comment: Yah this is great